# Content Negotiation: Route according to Accept header in Micronaut

Tags: micronaut

In HTTP, you can define a `Accept`header to specify, which content you want to retrieve:

```
curl --header "Accept: text/plain" localhost:8080/greetings/
curl --header "Accept: application/xml" localhost:8080/greetings/
```

I wonder, if there is a bult-in solution to Micronaut to handle this.

There is a blog post (https://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2018/08/micronaut-mastery-return-response-based.html) which describes how to produce different output depending on the `Accept` header. But this does not feel right to me, as most things in Micronaut are handled by annotations.

I tried to use `@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)`, but this only applies to POST requests (which is quite obvious, as Micronaut does not *consume* data on a GET request). The `@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)` annotation seems to set the `content type` header and configure output encoding, but does not seem to interact with the routing.

```java
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @Get("/")
    String getXml() {
        return "<greeting>Hello World</greeting>";
    }

    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Get("/")
    String getPlaintext() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
```

While I hoped this would route a HTTP request with `Accept: text/plain` to getPlaintext() and `Accept: application/xml` to getXml(), it resulted in 2 matches of the incoming request:

`DEBUG i.m.h.s.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler - Encoding emitted response object [More than 1 route matched the incoming request. The following routes matched /greetings/: GET - /greetings, GET - /greetings] using codec: io.micronaut.jackson.codec.JsonMediaTypeCodec@41ffaeb8`

So, is there any built-in solution to route HTTP requests depending on their `Accept` header?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Micronaut route is chosen only via the uri match.
There was some discussion about [using Accept header in API versions](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/997). But still, `UriRouteMatch` does not take into account `MediaType`.

Comment: "Micronaut route is chosen only via the uri match." - That is not correct.  The uri is part of it but so is the request verb.

Comment: That is... you can have `@Get("/someuri")` and `@Post("/someuri")` attached to different methods and Micronaut knows how to handle that.  That doesn't help with what the question above is really about, but it does address the claim "Micronaut route is chosen only via the uri match.".  I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Routes currently don't take into account the accept header, however routes do take into account the `@Consumes` and the `Content-Type` header. You can have routes with the same URL that accept different data types and the one that matches the content type will be chosen.

You can create an issue on Github to bring this up for discussion. It may already be out there so be sure to search first